# Add a button after add to cart and redirect it to some custom link in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am adding a button after add to cart button using this hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', array($this, 'add_button'));
```

But when I click on that button it is doing the functionality of add to cart button.

How to customize that button link *(to some other page)*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the callback function `add_button` look like? Please edit your question to include the code instead of posting in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use **`woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button`** hook this way to get what you are expecting:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_custom_button', 10, 0 );
function add_custom_button() { 
    $my_custom_link = home_url('/my_page_slug/');
    echo '<a class="btn-atc" href="' . esc_url( $my_custom_link ) .'">' . __( "My text button", "my_theme_slug" )  . '</a>';
};
```

*Paste this code snippet in function.php file of your active child theme or theme.*

Then you will have to replace (in the code) the correct link path, button name and theme slug for:

- **`'/my_page_slug/'`**
- **`"My text button"`**
- **`"my_theme_slug"`**

This should work.

---

**This section is OUT of your question and it's about styling your button:**

You'll maybe need to add some custom CSS rules to the style.css file located in your active child theme or theme, for styling appearance of your custom button *(Use "btn-atc" class instead of "btn")*:

```css
/* Based on your comment */

a.btn-atc {
    background-color: #eee !important; 
    border: 2px solid #999; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
    border-radius: 3px; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-weight: 500; 
    line-height: 1.7em !important; 
    margin-left: 5px; 
    margin-top: -5px; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 0.3em 1em; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s; 
    transition: all 0.2s; 
}
a.btn-atc:hover {
    background-color: #666 !important; 
    color: #fff !important; 
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for Answer. i am tring to change the css of that button

echo '<button class="btn" href="' . esc_url( $my_custom_link ) .'">' . __( "My text button", "my_theme_slug" )  . '</button>';
     };
by using class as btn

Comment: Css script

.btn{margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: -5px;
position: relative;
padding: 0.3em 1em;
border: 2px solid;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
background: transparent;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 1.7em !important;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s;
transition: all 0.2s;
}

Comment: but still their is no changes in my button style