# Additional button in Woocommerce shop page and archives

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'd like to add a button next to "Add to Cart" on the product page that adds "-sample" to the product URL when clicked.

Example:

You're viewing Product 1's page and the URL is "`http://www.example.com/shop/product-1/`"

When you click on the button, it adds "-sample" to the URL
"`http://www.example.com/shop/product-1-sample/`"

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For woocommerce 3+** *(only)*:

In woocommerce 3 you will use `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` action hook instead, as the hook `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button` will not work anymore.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_custom_button', 10, 0 );
function add_custom_button() {
    global $product;

    $product_link = $product->get_permalink();

    $sample_link = substr($product_link, 0, -1) . '-sample/';
    echo '<a class="button alt btn-sample" href="' . esc_url( $sample_link ) .'">' . __( "Get a sample", "my_theme_slug" )  . '</a>';
}
```

Code goes on **`function.php`** file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Before woocommerce 3:**

This is possible using hook **`woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button`** to add your additional button on product pages, using this custom function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_custom_button', 10, 0 );
function add_custom_button() {
    global $product;

    $product_link = get_permalink( get_the_id() );

    $sample_link = substr($product_link, 0, -1) . '-sample/';
    echo '<a class="button alt btn-sample" href="' . esc_url( $sample_link ) .'">' . __( "Get a sample", "my_theme_slug" )  . '</a>';
}
```

*This code goes on **`function.php`** file of your active child theme or theme.*

**This code is tested and fully functional.**

---

Based on this: [Add a button after add to cart and redirect it to some custom link in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675675/add-a-button-after-add-to-cart-and-redirect-it-to-some-custom-link-in-woocommerc/38681079#38681079)

And this: [PHP - How to remove all specific characters at the end of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053830/php-how-to-remove-all-specific-characters-at-the-end-of-a-string/34120797#34120797)

Comment: For some reason this stopped working after the new WooCommerce update, any idea why?

Comment: Actually, it's this code that I added to only apply the button to a certain category, when I remove this code it works again. [Here's the Code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/remov-product-content-based-on-category/)

Comment: [Link to new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135772/woocommerce-display-code-only-in-certain-category)

Comment: Is it possible to add this to the shop page instead of the product page?

Comment: @DiegoM. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887186/additional-button-in-woocommerce-shop-page-and-archives/38888765#38888765

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since the original question, but here's a recent update that works for me, WooCommerce 6.3.1:

```
/* WooCommerce customization */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_select_link', 11 );
function custom_select_link() {
     global $product;
     // Custom "Select" button.
     echo '<a class="custom-button" href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ) . '"><button class="custom-button">   </button></a>';
}
```

This answer cites an answer in [wordpress.stackexchange.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112757/adding-button-to-shop-page-in-woocommerce)