# WooCommerce - Conditional has_term doesn't work anymore after updating

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

So I'm using the conditional of tho code Snippet from this [**example**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/remov-product-content-based-on-category/), with [**this thread code**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38888765/3730754) with success:

BUT It's no longer working after updating my WordPress Core and WooCommerce Plugin.

```
if ( is_product() && has_term( 'sample-category', 'product_cat' ) ){

    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_custom_button', 10, 0 );
    function add_custom_button() {
        global $products;

        $product_link = get_permalink( $products->id );
        $sample_link = substr($product_link, 0, -1) . '-swatch-card/';
        echo '<a class="button alt btn-sample" href="' . esc_url( $sample_link ) .'">' . __( "Order a Sample", "my_theme_slug" )  . '</a>';

    }

}
```

Child Plugin still has the proper code in the function.php file.

How can I solve this issue please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way may be, using $post global object and embedding the conditional inside your function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_custom_button', 10, 0 );
function add_custom_button() {
    global $post;
    if ( has_term( 'collection', 'product_cat', $post->ID ) ) {
        $product_link = get_permalink( $post->ID );
        $sample_link = substr($product_link, 0, -1) . '-swatch-card/';
        echo '<a class="button alt btn-sample" href="' . esc_url( $sample_link ) .'">' . __( "Order a Sample", "my_theme_slug" )  . '</a>';
    }
};
```

> The conditional has_term() needs sometimes it's third argument to work… In function.php it can't find the current post So in this case is better to embed it inside the function after $post or $product global object.

Comment: just to add a note, global $product doesn't work in WooCommerce 3.4.2. $post and $post->ID does